# Trouble with populating student's marks

Tags: c

This is in response to a similar threat I posted the other day with reading a file into the requisite data structure with the file data like so, I can't remember who said it but yes there's four subjects. (I wanted to post an overall reply to all responses but could only comment on each post made):

131782 Mathematics 59

075160 Mathematics 92

580313 Physics 63

073241 Mathematics 32

487476 Mathematics 73

075160 Physics 98

472832 English 44

...

I'm using fscanf() now to parse the data and this is a much better approach. I made another thread yesterday about removing duplicate strings. I've scrapped that idea now and just used qsort on the student IDs and created a for loop that skips every four elements and rings the unique student IDs into the structure. I did a printf() command earlier and they're successfully stored. Now I've got the IDs stored I'm now ready to search for that ID and populate their marks and I "think" it's almost there except for a slight problem inside the update_student() function.

If you look at my code, or even compile it, it's not liking the line that's supposed to populate the mark for the student, student_data[idx].marks[buffer_subjects]=marks. But buffer_subjects is a string but if you look at my defines those strings are constants which is the whole idea when it gets to this stage.

How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STUDENTS 20

#define COMPUTING 0
#define ENGLISH 1
#define MATHEMATICS 2
#define PHYSICS 3
#define SUBJECTS 4


#define ROWS 80
#define SIZE 100

int string_compare(void const *x, void const *y)
{      
    return strcmp(*(char**)x, *(char**)y);
} 

struct student
{
    char student_ID[SIZE];
    int marks[SUBJECTS];
};struct student student_data[STUDENTS];

int find_student(char buffer_IDs[])
{
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<STUDENTS;j++)
        if(strcmp(student_data[j].student_ID,buffer_IDs)==0)
            return j;
}

void update_student(char buffer_IDs[], char buffer_subjects[], int marks[])
{    
    int idx = find_student(buffer_IDs); 


    student_data[idx].marks[buffer_subjects] = marks;
}


int main(void)
{
    FILE *input;
    int i,j, data_items;
    char buffer_IDs[ROWS][SIZE];
    char buffer_subject[ROWS][SIZE];
    int marks[ROWS][SIZE];
    char *string_ptrs[ROWS];



    if((input=fopen("C:\\marks\\marks.txt","r"))==NULL)
        perror("File open failed!");
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)           
        {                
            while((data_items=fscanf(input, "%s %s %d", buffer_IDs[i], buffer_subject[i], marks[i])!=3));
            printf("%s %s %d\n", buffer_IDs[i], buffer_subject[i], *marks[i]);


            string_ptrs[i]=buffer_IDs[i];
        }

        putchar('\n');

        qsort(string_ptrs, sizeof(string_ptrs)/sizeof(char*), sizeof(char*), string_compare);

        for(i=0;i<ROWS;i=i+4)
        {
            j=0;
            strcpy(student_data[j].student_ID,string_ptrs[i]);

            printf("%s\n",student_data[j].student_ID); 
            j++;
        }

        for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
            update_student(buffer_IDs[i], buffer_subject[i], marks[i]);



    }
    return 0;
}

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Don't post threats, we do not bow to blackmail. If you meant thread, you are still dead wrong: This is not a forum. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: test.c:42:28: error: array subscript is not an integer
    student_data[idx].marks[buffer_subjects] = marks;
This is the error that I obtain. Can you understand it?

Comment: There is a warning even earlier. But **first reduce your code** to the minimum needed to illustrate your question, and **format it properly**.

Comment: What's the final return-value of function `find_student`? How does that thing even compile???

Comment: I can get it to compile, but then it hangs.  Looking at it now.

Comment: @barakmanos: Not returning a value from a non-void function is allowed, though really bad. Using the return-value results in UB then...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well that's very nice. Compilation errors are there to prevent runtime UB where possible (I'm pretty sure that the compiler would warn about it under the right compilation flags)... In any case, if it **does** compile, then it just makes things worse.

Comment: There are a LOT of things in this block of code that should be done differently, and fixing one thing seems to bring to light other problems.  This might take a while.  I'm up to getting core dumps now...

Comment: OP: Have you any experience with using a debugger such as gdb, or the one in VS?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous failures in this block of code.  I would seriously recommend building it up block by block, and using a debugger to confirm that the data in each stage is as expected, and not proceeding till each of the lower level blocks work (and do not produce compile errors).

Running it through GDB with some sample data suggests problems even at the point of reading in and parsing data from the file on disk.

We can assist with individual issues as they arise from this approach.